# SoundCloud API - Load entire set into scPlayer

Tags: soundcloud, audio-player

I want to get an entire set waveform overview like my Soundcloud homepage has.

```
.scPlayer({
    links: [{url: permalink_url, title: ""}]
```

where permalink_url is my set's URL - it will only load one track at a time. Is there a way to get it to behave similar to my Soundcloud homepage, where the entire set is visible (and playable) as a single waveform?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get it to behave similar to my soundcloud homepage,
>   where the entire set is visible (and playable) as a single waveform?

Nope, sorry, you'd need to write that functionality yourself based on our API.

Comment: hmmm... i didn't realize that was even possible. so could i, for example, append a set's waveforms one after the other in a single widget container?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. What kind of widget container? In API response you'd get a URL of a waveform (PNG image), you could then stack them together and show progress accordingly. It'd require some work though.

Comment: i see. we are currently using the sc widget (with customized css) combined with the api calls to sort our tracks based on category. the problem is that some of these are single tracks and others are sets. ideally we would want the sets to have the tracks juxtaposed (like on our sc homepage). i don't know if i have the skills to hack it at the level you are describing though.